# Prolog is giving random numbers instead of string in read write command

Tags: prolog

```
say_hi:-
    write('Your name? '),
    read(X),
    write('hi'),
    write(X).
```

*THIS IS MY CODE BUT!!!
THIS HAPPEN WHEN I RUN IT. WHY?*

```
?- say_hi.
Your name? Ali.
hi_884
true.
```

It's not giving

```
> hi Ali
```

. WHY?

please guide me and give me simple code to read and write name.
every time put different name it gives different numbers.

Comment: The code works, where is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

This happens because read/1 is meant to parse *Prolog terms*, and a sequence of letters starting with an uppercase letter is a *variable*. The strange `_NNN` output is - conventionally - the way Prolog display an *uninstantiated* variable. In SWI-Prolog you can use [read_line_to_codes/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=readutil) or read_line_to_string/2 to get your string. For example

```
?- read_line_to_string(user_input,S).
|: Ali
S = "Ali".
```